# How to add environment as prefix in all alerts triggered by Alertmanager

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I am using alert manager with Prometheus. Here is my alert manager config. I am sending alerts from multiple systems(dev,QA) to one channel. Is there a way I can prefix string or environment name to all the alerts?

```
route:
  group_by: ['alertname']
  group_interval: 30s
  repeat_interval: 30s
  group_wait: 30s
  receiver: 'prometheus-msteams'

receivers:
- name: 'prometheus-msteams'
  webhook_configs: 
  - send_resolved: true
    url: 'http://prometheus-msteams:2000/alertmanager'
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'from multiple environments'? Is it different prometheuses or different rules or different time series?

Comment: I am having the same application with the same Prometheus rules on 3-4 environments. Now I am having same alert channel, so it's difficult to know the environment sent the alert

Comment: You could simply add the environment as an alert annotation…